# Theano package of Python (Canopy) returns an error: cannot import name gof

Tags: python, canopy, theano, scikits

This this the error returns using  `from sknn.mlp import *` in `Enthought Canopy` :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User_Account\Desktop\axxx.py in <module>()
----> 1 from sknn.mlp import *

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sknn\mlp.py in <module>()
     13 
     14 import numpy
---> 15 import theano
     16 import sklearn.base
     17 import sklearn.pipeline

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py in <module>()
     53     object2, utils)
     54 
---> 55 from theano.compile import (
     56     SymbolicInput, In,
     57     SymbolicOutput, Out,

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
      7         SpecifyShape, specify_shape, register_specify_shape_c_code)
      8 
----> 9 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     10 
     11 from theano.compile.mode import *

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 import theano
---> 17 from theano import gof
     18 from theano.compat import partial
     19 import theano.compile.mode

ImportError: cannot import name gof 

In [3]: %run "C:/Users/Rahimikia/Desktop/axxx.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User_Account\Desktop\axxx.py in <module>()
----> 1 import theano

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py in <module>()
     53     object2, utils)
     54 
---> 55 from theano.compile import (
     56     SymbolicInput, In,
     57     SymbolicOutput, Out,

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
      7         SpecifyShape, specify_shape, register_specify_shape_c_code)
      8 
----> 9 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     10 
     11 from theano.compile.mode import *

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 import theano
---> 17 from theano import gof
     18 from theano.compat import partial
     19 import theano.compile.mode

ImportError: cannot import name gof 

In [4]: %run "C:/Users/Rahimikia/Desktop/axxx.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User_Account\Desktop\axxx.py in <module>()
----> 1 import theano

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py in <module>()
     53     object2, utils)
     54 
---> 55 from theano.compile import (
     56     SymbolicInput, In,
     57     SymbolicOutput, Out,

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
      7         SpecifyShape, specify_shape, register_specify_shape_c_code)
      8 
----> 9 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     10 
     11 from theano.compile.mode import *

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 import theano
---> 17 from theano import gof
     18 from theano.compat import partial
     19 import theano.compile.mode

ImportError: cannot import name gof 

In [5]: %run "C:/Users/Rahimikia/Desktop/axxx.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User_Account\Desktop\axxx.py in <module>()
----> 1 import theano

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py in <module>()
     53     object2, utils)
     54 
---> 55 from theano.compile import (
     56     SymbolicInput, In,
     57     SymbolicOutput, Out,

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py in <module>()
      7         SpecifyShape, specify_shape, register_specify_shape_c_code)
      8 
----> 9 from theano.compile.function_module import *
     10 
     11 from theano.compile.mode import *

C:\Users\User_Account\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 import theano
---> 17 from theano import gof
     18 from theano.compat import partial
     19 import theano.compile.mode

ImportError: cannot import name gof
```

How can i solve this problem? I installed `mingw` and `libpython` using package manager and installed `Theano` developer version using `pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` in windows 8.1 .

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: Canopy default python version. I think it is `2.7.6 ` .

Comment: If you 'think', we only can speculate.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the history of this bug here:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2406

It says

> The problem appears to be that the compilation is trying to link with
>   the static library libpython2.7.a, instead of the dynamic version of
>   the library (which should be something like libpython2.7.so).

and later

> Hey,thanks for your reply, I did remake python and do altinstall
>   ,solved this problem.

You should rebuild Python and it'll be fine.

**UPDATE**

I think you should get rid of Canopy and install Python manually. Canopy seems to be a ready-built distribution of Python and some scientific packages and I guess Theano will not work in it at this moment.

Google for instructions how to install python on windows (I never used windows systems), for example this one: http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2014/02/16/setting-up-python-in-windows-8-1/

And then install all required packages via `pip`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I rebuild (remake) Python?

Comment: As discussed here Canopy support installing Theano : http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html